# Trying to access data from my mongoDB and push to a <table> in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to simply take data which is stored in mongoDB and push it to a table in HTML. I need to access the **hangman** database > **players** collection which simply holds **name** & **score**. Please could someone point out where I have gone wrong?

However my Chrome console error is: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

[image: My mongoDB]

**The leadership.html page code**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>NAME</th><th>SCORE</th></tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody id="leadership"></tbody>
</table>  



<script>
    $(function() {
        $.get("http://localhost:9000/", {}, function (res) {
        //let data = res;
        const { data } = res;
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                let name = data[i].name;
                let score = data[i].score;
                //let score = score[score.length - 1];

                console.log(data[i].name);
                console.log(res);

                $("#leadership").append("<tr><td class=\"name\">"
                    + data[i].name + "</td><td class=\"score\">" 
                    + data[i].score + "</td></tr>");
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

**server.js**

```
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.status(200).sendFile("/", {root: "client"});
});
```

**CONSOLE'S ERROR MSG**
[image: Console's error message]
Line 69:  refers to `for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set correct route for getting data

```
  $.get("localhost:9000/getPlayers", {}, function (res) {
   ...
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use score before it's initialized.

```
let score = score[score.length - 1];
```

I guess you wanted to use data.score.

Comment: Hello, so i've tried to replace that line with `let score = data[i].score;` and I get `undefined` show in the table

Answer (score 0):

the problem is

```
let score = score[score.length - 1];
```

You define score into an element of score (which you didn't defined).

What do you wanna define score into?

also, it seems like both

```
let name = data[i].name;
let score = score[score.length - 1];
```

can be removed because you are adding the data of data[i].name / data[i].score so you don't need to define this.